# Puppet Install Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, puppet

I am trying to install Apache Tomcat via Puppet.

I am using the module https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/tomcat and following the instructions given there

My puppet code is

```
node 'xx' {

   include configuretomcat
   include tomcat
   include epel

 }  

class { 'tomcat':
  install_from_source => false,
}
class { 'epel': }


class configuretomcat {

  tomcat::instance{ 'default':
  package_name        => 'tomcat',
  catalina_base => '/opt/apache-tomcat/tomcat',
  }

  tomcat::service { 'default':
  use_jsvc     => false,
  use_init     => true,
  service_name => 'tomcat',
  }

}
```

However the Tomcat installation has no applications deployed in webapps. ie no ROOT or manager application. Am I doing something wrong?

The epel class is https://forge.puppetlabs.com/stahnma/epel

Comment: list and show me what you get under folder `webapps`

Comment: That is the issue with this approach - the webapps directory is empty. I had to download from a source instead

Comment: Could you update the configuration @IanWatson